# Creating a Composite Input Component

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component, composite-component

I'm trying to create a composite component that is an input component, similar to the one laid out in this tutorial: [Composite Input Components in JSF](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2010/01/30/composite-input-components-jsf)

The component uses an p:autocomplete from primefaces, and a p:selectonemenu, with an optional p:inputText to take in some additional text, it will then return to the backing bean an object which wraps this information neatly for other parts of the web application to use. Unfortunately, I can't ever seem to get the values back. Here is the code:

The component xhtml:

```
<cc:interface componentType="personselector">

    <!-- Subject ID for contact filtering -->
    <cc:attribute name="subjectId" type="java.lang.String" required="false"/>
    <!-- Whether or not to show the individual contacted free form field -->
    <cc:attribute name="showIndividualContacted" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" default="false"/>
    <!-- Whether or not to show the phone selector -->
    <cc:attribute name="showPhoneSelector" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" default="true"/>
    <!-- The style class to apply to the parent div -->
    <cc:attribute name="styleClass" type="java.lang.String" required="false"/>
    <!-- An optional listener for a newly selected person -->
    <cc:attribute name="personSelectedListener" method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)" required="false"/>
    <!-- The label to display next to the person selector -->
    <cc:attribute name="personLabel" type="java.lang.String" required="false" default="Person"/>
    <!-- The label to display next to the individual contacted field -->
    <cc:attribute name="individualLabel" type="java.lang.String" required="false" default="Individual Contacted"/>
    <!-- The label to display next to the phone number selector -->
    <cc:attribute name="phoneLabel" type="java.lang.String" required="false" default="Phone Number"/>
    <!-- Whether or not to limit the phone number results to a certain type of number, valid options are "phone" or "fax" -->
    <cc:attribute name="limitPhones" type="java.lang.String" required="false"/>
</cc:interface> 

<cc:implementation>

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}" class="personselector #{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="person-selector-grid">
            <h:outputLabel styleClass="personselector-ui-label" value="#{cc.attrs.personLabel}" />
            <p:autoComplete id="personSelector" value="#{cc.personSelected}" completeMethod="#{cc.searchPeople}" 
                var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item}" size="51" converter="personSearchConverter" 
                onSelectUpdate="@this" selectListener="#{cc.handlePersonSelect}" 
                styleClass="personselector-ui-autocomplete personselector-mainperson">

                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{cc.handlePersonSelect}" process=":#{cc.clientId}" update="phoneNumberSelector" />

                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.personSelectedListener}" disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.personSelectedListener}"/>

                ... auto complete formatting ...

            </p:autoComplete>

            <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.individualLabel}" styleClass="personselector-ui-label" rendered="#{cc.attrs.showIndividualContacted}"/>
            <p:inputText id="individualField" value="#{cc.individualName}" styleClass="personselector-individual-contacted personselector-ui-textfield" 
                                rendered="#{cc.attrs.showIndividualContacted}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.phoneLabel}" styleClass="personselector-ui-label"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="phoneNumberSelector" value="#{cc.phoneNumber}" editable="true" var="n" style="width:150px" 
                                            styleClass="personselector-ui-selectone personselector-phone-selector">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.findPersonContactNumbers}" var="number" itemValue="#{number.number}"/>

                <p:column>
                    #{n.descr}
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    #{n.number}
                </p:column>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

The backing bean for the component:

```
@FacesComponent("personselector")
public class PersonSelector extends UIInput implements NamingContainer{

public static final String PHONE_LIMIT ="phone";
public static final String FAX_LIMIT = "fax";

//Required for since we're extending UIInput and not UINamingContainer
@Override
public String getFamily() { return "javax.faces.NamingContainer"; }

//Returns this component as a submitted value rather than the individual sub component key values
// See http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2010/01/30/composite-input-components-jsf
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() { return this; }


//Convert from the component to the SelectedPerson object we want to return
@Override
protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object newSubmittedValue) {
    AutoComplete personSelector = (AutoComplete) findComponent("personSelector");
    UIInput individualField = (UIInput) findComponent("individualField");
    SelectOneMenu phoneSelector = (SelectOneMenu) findComponent("phoneNumberSelector");
    PersonSearchData person = (PersonSearchData) personSelector.getValue();
    String individual = (String) individualField.getValue();
    PhoneNumber phone = (PhoneNumber) phoneSelector.getValue();
    if(person != null || !StaticTools.isNullOrEmpty(individual) || phone!= null){
        SelectedPerson sp = new SelectedPerson();
        sp.setAlternateName(individual);
        sp.setPersonSelected(person);
        sp.setPhoneNumberSelected(phone);
        return sp;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException{
    SelectedPerson ps = (SelectedPerson) getValue();
    if(ps != null){
        AutoComplete personSelector = (AutoComplete) findComponent("personSelector");
        UIInput individualField = (UIInput) findComponent("individualField");
        SelectOneMenu phoneSelector = (SelectOneMenu) findComponent("phoneNumberSelector");

        personSelector.setValue(ps.getPersonSelected());
        personSelected = ps.getPersonSelected();

        individualField.setValue(ps.getAlternateName());
        individualName = ps.getAlternateName();

        phoneSelector.setValue(ps.getPhoneNumberSelected());
        phoneNumber = ps.getPhoneNumberSelected();
    }

    super.encodeBegin(context);
}

/** The state of the component. */
private Object[] state;

/** The person selected. */
private PersonSearchData personSelected;

/** The individual name. */
private String individualName;

/** The phone number selected. */
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

/** The subject id for filtering results. */
private String mySubjectId;

/** The limitation placed on the phone results. */
private String myPhoneLimit;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase#saveState(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)
 */
@Override
public Object saveState(final FacesContext context){
    if (state == null) {
        state = new Object[4];
    }

    state[0] = super.saveState(context);
    state[1] = personSelected;
    state[2] = individualName;
    state[3] = phoneNumber;
    return state;

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase#restoreState(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public void restoreState(final FacesContext context, final Object state) {
    this.state = (Object[]) state;
    super.restoreState(context, this.state[0]);
    personSelected =  (PersonSearchData) this.state[1];
    individualName = (String) this.state[2];
    phoneNumber = (PhoneNumber) this.state[3];
}

public String getMySubjectId(){
    if(mySubjectId == null){
        mySubjectId = (String) getAttributes().get("subjectId");
    }
    return mySubjectId;
}

/**
 * Find respondent contacts.
 * 
 * @param query
 *            the query
 * @return the list
 */
public List<PersonSearchData> searchPeople(String query) {
    ... find people from the database...
}

/**
 * Find matching contacts.
 * 
 * @param queryLength   the query length
 * @param firstName     the first name
 * @param lastName      the last name
 * @return the list
 */
public List<PersonSearchData> findMatchingPeople(int queryLength,
        String firstName, String lastName) {
    ... filter people ...
}

/**
 * Handle respondent select.
 * 
 * @param event
 *            the event
 */
public void handlePersonSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    PersonSearchData data = (PersonSearchData) event.getObject();

    setPersonSelected(data);
}

/**
 * Gets the find respondent contact numbers.
 * 
 * @return the find respondent contact numbers
 */
public List<SelectItem> getFindPersonContactNumbers() {
    PersonSearchData respondentContact = getPersonSelected();

    return findContactNumbers(respondentContact, getMyPhoneLimit(), getPhoneNumber());
}


/**
 * Find contact numbers.
 *
 * @param psd the psd
 * @param phoneLimit the phone limit
 * @param current the current
 * @return the list
 */
public List<SelectItem> findContactNumbers(PersonSearchData psd,
        String phoneLimit,
        PhoneNumber current) {
    ... find phone/fax numbers from the database ...
}

... getters and setters ...
}
```

Usage:

```
<h:form>
        <ppa:personselector id="mySelector" value="#{homePageBacking.sp}"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{homePageBacking.displayData}" value="Submit Me"/>
    </h:form>
```

Unfortunately, I never get back the submitted values. If I use state saving as I've implemented here, I do get back the PersonSelected from the auto complete, but I never get back the selected phone number or individual name (they come back as null). If I don't use state saving, then everything comes back null.